# How to put your own Server online?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, application-server

I'm new learner to servers. I installed Ubuntu Server on my computer.

**Questions:**

- My question is how to put your own server online?
- Which speed is need to put your own server online?
- Which applications need?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all,  what do you mean with: put server online? Do you want to make a web server? If Yes, to put it online you have to know your public ip address. You can also obfuscate It using a dns service like duckdns or no-ip. In this way you have an address like this: yourpreferredname.no-ip.biz and not xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Next, you have to setup a webserver, maybe using Apache and MySQL? There are lot of tutorial online how to setup a LAMP SERVER. Next, open port 80 of Ubuntu with

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Open the port of your server in your modem's port forwarding and set the port 80 as private (lan) and public (Wan).

Then,
With browser go to yourpreferredname.no-ip.biz or your piblic io address and you'll see your apache working.

For the speed: there isn't a good answer, if you Will have hundred of users, don't need wonderful server but at least 30mbs in upload. For thousand or more user 100 mbs in upload at least. Is very relative, this is a general answer for a general question.

Applications needed? What do you want to build? As i said before: if you want to make

- LAMP server [maybe here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

  - SMTP server? [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)
  - Node js? [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Yes to make your own web site online.

Comment: Ok, install LAMP server with the link i wrote, open ports, go online. If you need a 24h 7/7 server i'll consider the idea ti buy a dedicated server or VPS.